# What does "None" mode mean in Image.fromarray?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am converting from a numpy array to an image using the

```
Image.fromarray()
```

The docstring shows that the default mode is "None". What does that mean? Is it one of the modes such as "L", or is it another mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify a mode or specify None, it will decide which mode to use from the type.

(The authors of the Image class appear not to know how to write a Python docstring; the doc comments are all there in the source, but as comments rather than a docstring.)